# Why does ATP inhibit glycogen synthase?

Tags: biochemistry

Why is ATP an inhibitor? I mean, if there are high levels of ATP, it means that the cell has adequate amounts of energy. Therefore, if it doesn't need the energy, then glucose needs not go through glycolysis to produce that energy and is more practical to be stored as glycogen. So why is ATP an inhibitor of glycogen synthase?

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading the question, but it sounds like it would be more fitting on [Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com). It sounds like you are asking why physiologically this occurs rather than what chemically causes ATP to inhibit it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I will put across main points so that it will be easy to understand this complex control mechanisms of the enzymes involved in both processes:

**Glycogen synthase control**

Control of glycogen metabolism is effected via reciprocal **regulation of glycogen phosphorylase and glycogen synthase**. Thus, activation of glycogen phosphorylase is tightly linked to inhibition of glycogen synthase, and vice versa.

Both glycogen synthesis and breakdown are **exergonic** under the same physiological conditions. If both pathways operate simultaneously, however this is deemed to be **wasteful hydrolysis of UTP**.

Glycogen phosphorylase and glycogen synthase therefore must be under stringent control such that glycogen is either synthesized or utilized according to cellular needs.
Regulation involves both **allosteric control** and **covalent modification**, with the latter being under hormonal control.

> Glycogen synthase also exists in two distinct forms that can be
>   interconverted by the action of specific enzymes: active,
>   dephosphorylated glycogen synthase I (glucose- 6-P–independent) and
>   less active, phosphorylated glycogen synthase D (glucose-6-
>   P–dependent). Glycogen synthase, is activated by G6P.When there is
>   high demand for ATP (low [ATP], low [G6P], and high [AMP]), glycogen
>   phosphorylase is stimulated and glycogen synthase is inhibited, so
>   flux through this pathway favours glycogen breakdown.

Why is this so?

**ATP** also binds to the allosteric effector site, but in the T state, so that it **inhibits** rather than promotes the T-R conformational shift.
Having said that here is an illustration of control of glycogen phosphorylase activity;

[image: glycogen- enzymes]

> The enzyme may assume the enzymatically inactive T conformation or the
>   catalytically active R form. The conformation of phosphorylase b is
>   allosterically controlled by effectors such as AMP, ATP, and G6P and
>   is mostly in the T state under physiological conditions. In contrast,
>   the modified form of the enzyme, phosphorylase a, is largely
>   unresponsive to these effectors and is mostly in the R state unless
>   there is a high level of glucose.

**Exactly this situation occurs in glycogen metabolism through the opposition of the glycogen phosphorylase and glycogen synthase reactions.**

Another point to note is that glycogen synthase is regulated by covalent modification through complex cyclic cascade. For more information, please see here: [Glycogen Metabolism](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/bcbp/molbiochem/MBWeb/mb1/part2/glycogen.htm)

If you need more clarification don't hesitate to put in comments. Hope it helps

References

1. Biochemistry (Grisham)
2. Biochemistry (Voet and Voet)
3. Harper’s Illustrated Biochemistry

Comment: ATP was mentioned to be an inhibitor of *glycogen synthase* (Campbell and Farrell, 2009). However, in the book it gives no further explanation about this. What I seem to get from your answer is that ATP inhibits the transition to R state of *glycogen phosphorylase* which is besides the point. However, thanks for the note on the controls of ATP on both enzymes. I just cant really get why the aforementioned authors said that ATP inhibits glycogen synthase.

Comment: @angrycarbocation remember the two enzymes are reciprocal and yes ATP is an inhibitor, that's what I was explaining in the answer. Read bold words please, the enzymes essentially "act" the same way although the for different pathways

Comment: *(low [ATP], low [G6P], and high [AMP]), glycogen phosphorylase is stimulated and glycogen synthase is inhibited* Is ATP still an inhibitor of glycogen synthase or is it for glycogen phosphorylase?

Comment: What I got from the explanation and the bold words is that ATP is an inhibitor of the phosphorylase and not the synthase which is a direct contradiction of the statement in my reference.

Comment: @angrycarbocation it is essentially true for glycogen synthase . ATP is an allosteric effector for glycogen synthase hence inhibitor and that what's in the answer, for illustration I had to use the other enzyme but it's very similar to glycogen synthase

Comment: If both phosphorylase and synthase are inhibited by ATP then doesn't that contradict itself since the two enzymes are antagonists of each other? And why the prev statement about low ATP --> synthase gets inhibited? @xavier_fakerat

Comment: Precisely  @angrycarbocation. I see where there is a slight confusion , while ATP it's true that the synthase enzyme is inhibited by ATP,  the same statement is true because when ATP binds to phosphorylase it does so in the T state such that it inhibits than promotes, also on your second statement, **since both pathways can occur spontaneously, it only done in the interest of saving UTP rather than wasting it, in addition other regulation mechanisms come into like cyclic cascades (hormonal influence) so it's not a must that glycogenolysis must occur when there is slightly less ATP**

Comment: Oh, so in essence, the action of ATP as a negative effector is the same for both phosphorylase and synthase (T/R interconversion)? So ATP isnt really the one that's controlling the pathway, since doing so would lead to the same action of the two enzymes. @xavier_fakerat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57255/discussion-between-xavier-fakerat-and-angrycarbocation).